# can we drop a file to a folder location automatically using camel,or at a set period of time(not intervals)?

Tags: apache-camel

Iam trying to automate the testing of a java bundle,Which will process once a  file is dropped in a particular folder.

can we drop a file to a folder location automatically using camel,or at a set period of time(not intervals)?

is this possible purely by camel or should we incorporate other frameworks?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

sure, you can use the [camel-file](http://camel.apache.org/file.html) component to produce (create files somewhere) and consume (read/process files from somewhere) and optionally control the initial/polling delays easily with attributes...

here is a simple example of consuming->processing->producing

```
from("file://inputdir").process(<dosomething>).to("file://outputdir")
```

alternatively, you could periodically produce a file and drop it somewhere

```
from("timer://foo?fixedRate=true&period=60000").process(<createFileContent>").to("file://inputdir");
```

Answer (score -1):

Although camel could do this by creating a timer endpoint, then setting the file content and writing to a file endpoint, my answer would be to simply use a bash script. No camel needed here.

Pseudo bash script:

```
while [ true ]
do
   cp filefrom fileto
   pauze 10s
done
```

Comment: a bad idea since: 1) a bash script can't be integrated in tests and 2) it's not flexible (by means of params tweaking as part of the test cases). Also the question is about Apache Camel